# "libpcap.so is not a regular file" error when building jNetPcap on ARM processor

Tags: java, gcc, ant, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile jNetPcap source on my Raspberry Pi, but am being met with the following error when I run ant compile.

```
[exec] Can't do inplace edit: ./build/lib/libpcap.so is not a regular file.
[exec] Result: 1
[echo] Fixed SONAME: ./build/lib/libpcap.so
[echo] readelf: Error: './build/lib/libpcap.so' is not an ordinary file
...
BUILD FAILED
/home/pi/myDir/build.xml:731: gcc failed with return code 1
```

Line 731 (and on) of build.xml is:

```
...
<cc runtime="dynamic" outtype="shared" outfile="${build.lib.dir}/${lib.pcap.basename}" debug="${compiler.debug}" objdir="${build.obj.dir}" multithreaded="compiler.multithreaded" exceptions="compiler.exceptions" warnings="${compiler.warnings}">

    <env key="PATH" path="${compiler.cc.bin.dir};${env.PATH}" />

    <fileset dir="${src.c.dir}" />
    <includepath location="${build.include.dir}" />
    <includepath location="${src.c.dir}" />
    <sysincludepath location="${java.sdk.include.dir}" />
    <sysincludepath location="${java.sdk.include.dir}/linux" />
    <defineset define="LIBPCAP_VERSION=0x${compiler.LIBPCAP_VERSION}" if="compiler.LIBPCAP_VERSION" />
    <defineset define="DEBUG" if="DEBUG" />

    <linker name="${compiler.ld.cmd}">
        <syslibset libs=":../lib/libpcap.so" />

        <linkerarg value="-Wl,-soname,lib${lib.pcap.basename}.so" />

        <linkerarg value="-lstdc++" />
    </linker>
</cc>
...
```

It seems the root issue is that ".so" files are somehow special, so they need to be handled differently (As a side note; maybe this build.xml works in Ubuntu because it knows to treat ".so" files the same as normal files). I just don't know how to modify this build.xml so that they are treated like the special files they are.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use following attribute to fix. it is working at my end on Linux. try may it work on raspberry pi. but i am not sure.

```
<linker> 
      <libset libs="pcap" />
      <libset dir="path of lib" libs="pcap" />
</linker>
```

Without .so and lib